# Snort 2.9.13 Error: Cant start DAQ (-1) --> Fatal Error quiting

Tags: windows-10, snort

I have installed Snort 2.9.13 on Windows 10. When I try to check the interfaces with `Snort -W`, it doesn't show any. However, using Windows' `ipconfig` they are visible.
[image]

When I test Snort using `snort -i 0 -c c:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -T`, it works fine:
[image]

However, when I try using it with `snort -i 0 -c c:\Snort\etc\snort.conf - A Console`, it gives me this error:
[image]

I tried running snort in admin mode and also reinstalled it using admin mode, but it didn't change anything. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `wpcap.dll` and `Packet.dll` from the `snort\bin\` directory and (re)-install NPcap in Winpcap API compatibility mode. This should solve your issue I was having the same problem and just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have an error with your winpcap installation.

Solve it or reinstall the winpcap and it will work for you.